# How can I set up a simple select form for a user's "items per page" preference?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, select, cookies

I'd like to have a simple select input box with a couple options for "items per page".  I'd like to save the new setting (cookie, preferred) and refresh the page on change.  I don't need the items on the page to reset without reloading the page, so I can pick up the cookie with PHP and limit accordingly.

```
<label>Items per page</label>
<select name="itemsPerPage">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Can you point me in the right direction?  I'm running PHP on the server and jQuery for javascript.

Comment: what server side framework are you using?

Comment: I expect JavaScript to handle the cookie setting, if possible.  Since I don't want the user to have to click a "submit" button, but rather reset the cookie "onchange" and have PHP pull the cookie preference on refresh.

Comment: well generally you don't want a whole dump from your database.

Comment: I agree. I'll certainly ensure that the max does not exceed the max my db connection can handle at load.  Is that what you're suggesting?  That a user could change their cookie to say 9999999?  I'm not concerned.  The max they'll get is the max I'll allow them to get.

Comment: are you asking how you create a cookie in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should set the cookie to the value of the select box and refresh the page.

You can get the cookie jquery plugin at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie.

```
$("select[name=itemsPerPage]").change(function(e) {

    $.cookie("itemsPerPage", $(e.target).val());

    window.location.reload();   

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's much easier to handle cookies in PHP, since I find javascript cookies to be a pain. This is how I would do it:

javascript:

```
$('select [name="itemsPerPage"]').change(function() {
    window.location="/myPage.php?items=" + $(this).val();
}
```

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_GET['items'])) {
    setcookie("itemsPerPage", $_GET['items']);
}

$itemsPerPage = (!empty($_COOKIE['items']) ? $_COOKIE['items'] : 10);
```